# Mongo Database update

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongo and I am looking for a help.

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.servmon.find({ "hostName" : “server-prf-004”})   
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58f0a4a2ff980d97cce0a79c"), "hostName" : “server-prf-004", "thresholds" : [ { "warn" : "None", "crit" : "None", "contact_mail" : "None", "type" : "loadcheck", "contact_page" : "None" }, { "warn" : "None", "crit" : "None", "contact_mail" : "None", "type" : "mu_check", "contact_page" : "None" }, { "map" : "/ora,/arch", "crit" : "None", "warn" : "None", "contact_mail" : "None", "type" : "diskmon", "contact_page" : "None" } ] }
```

If I want to change only one the entry in the database

```
{ "warn" : "None", "crit" : "None", "contact_mail" : "None", "type" : "loadcheck", "contact_page" : "None” } to  to { "warn" : “90", "crit" : “80", "contact_mail" : "None", "type" : "loadcheck", "contact_page" : "None” }
```

What is the best option?

I tried with update and findModify, but it is updating all entries after thresholds, like this:

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.servmon.findAndModify ( { query:{"hostName" : “server-prf-004","thresholds" : { "warn" : "None", "crit" : "None", "contact_mail" : "None", "type" : "mu_check", "contact_page" : "None" } }, update :{ "hostName" : "server-prf-002","thresholds" : { "warn" : "80", "crit" : "90", "contact_mail" : "None", "type" : "mu_check", "contact_page" : "None" }  } ,upsert: true } )

MongoDB Enterprise > db.servmon.find({ "hostName" : “server-prf-004"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58f0a4a2ff980d97cce0a799"), "hostName" : "server-prf-001", "thresholds" : { "warn" : "80", "crit" : "90", "contact_mail" : "None", "type" : "mu_check", "contact_page" : "None" } }
MongoDB Enterprise >
```

Comment: You want to change only one, but based on what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Performs an update
>   of the selected document. The update field employs the same update
>   operators or field: value specifications to modify the selected
>   document.
>
> The update() method either modifies specific fields in existing
>   documents or replaces an existing document entirely.

You are using the update variant which replaces the document completely.

What you need is update variant which uses update operator to selectively update fields.

Something like

`db.servmon.findAndModify ( { query:{"hostName" : "server-prf-004", "thresholds" : { "warn" : "None", "crit" : "None", "contact_mail" : "None", "type" : "mu_check", "contact_page" : "None" } }, update :{ $set:{ "hostName" : "server-prf-002", "thresholds.$" : { "warn" : "80", "crit" : "90", "contact_mail" : "None", "type" : "mu_check", "contact_page" : "None" } }  } ,upsert: true } )`

Note : `$set` is a update operator which updates `hostname` and `thresholds.$` which updates the selected array from query to update value using positional operator.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#dbcmd.findAndModify

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-parameter

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you just want to update one document even when your query produces one or more results. You can try this. Use a findOne query to return an _id which will be unique. Then use that _id in the update field. Here it is in one operation.

```
db.update({_id:
                db.servmon.findOne(
                    {
                        "hostName" : “server-prf-004",
                        "thresholds" : { "warn" : "None", "crit" : "None", "contact_mail" : "None", "type" : "mu_check", "contact_page" : "None" } 
                    })['_id']
            }
            {
                $set:
                    {
                         "hostName" : "server-prf-002","thresholds" : { "warn" : "80", "crit" : "90", "contact_mail" : "None", "type" : "mu_check", "contact_page" : "None" }


                    }
            },
            {upsert:true})
```